# JavaFX making a grid of items

Tags: java, gridview, javafx

I am working with an array of items I would love to display in form of a grid in JavaFX like its done in MS Word [image]

In Android we have a `RecyclerView` that can be a `listview` or a `gridview` depending on layout manager set, is there such a thing in JavaFX? I cannot find a tutorial on how to make a gridview, if anyone has an idea please share
Below is a cell I would like to display as a grid cell

```
public class TicketCell extends ListCell<Ticket> { 
private static final String TAG = TicketCell.class.getSimpleName();
private Logger logger;
private Ticket ticket;
@FXML
private Label lbDescription;
@FXML
private HBox parent;  
@FXML
private ImageView imgTicketImage;
private FXMLLoader mLLoader;


  public TicketCell(){
    logger = Logger.getLogger(MainWindowController.class);
    BasicConfigurator.configure(); 
  if (mLLoader == null) {
            mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/fxml/TicketDesignCell.fxml"));
            mLLoader.setController(this);

            try {
                mLLoader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(TAG, e);
            }

}
}


public void updateItem(Ticket pos,boolean empty){
super.updateItem(pos, empty);

if(pos == null){
setText(null);
setGraphic(null);
}else{




    this.lbDescription.setText(pos.getDescription());
    this.imgTicketImage.setCache(true);
    this.imgTicketImage.setSmooth(true);
    this.imgTicketImage.setImage(new Image(pos.getImageUrl()));



    setText(null);
    setGraphic(parent);


}

}
```

And how I use it

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable, EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

private static final String TAG = MainWindowController.class.getSimpleName();
private JFXListView lsTicketDesign;
private ObservableList<Ticket> ticketDesignList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private Stage stage;

public void setMyStage(Stage myStage) {
    this.stage = myStage;


}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    this.tabPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty());
    this.tabPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty());
    logger = Logger.getLogger(MainWindowController.class);
    ticketDesignList.add(new Ticket(1, "resources/images/template_01.png",  "Basic ticket template"));
    lsTicketDesign.setItems(ticketDesignList);
    lsTicketDesign.autosize();
    lsTicketDesign.setCellFactory(ticketDesignList -> new  TicketCell()); 

    lsTicketDesign.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListenerImpl());

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) or [FlowPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html)?

Comment: Or [`TilePane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html)? The standard layout panes are all described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: Or a [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html)???